# uploading media files for free that doesn't required credit card details on heroku django

Tags: django, heroku

I have uploaded my project on Heroku but media file(image) disappears after a while. When searching I found out that Heroku runs your application on dynos and dynos go to sleep after 30 minutes if there is not request comes, this makes Heroku not preserve user upload media files between dynos restart.

Is there any other way I can upload my media files that stays there? I could use Amazon S3 service but I don't have any credit card or don't want to use a credit card info? Is there any other way?

Comment: this isn't really a question for stack overflow. If you don't want to use your credit card use another services. or pay the 3$ for heroku to keep your app running. pythonanywhere might be a solution...

Comment: @ well said  hansTheFranz,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPpIubhqWR4